# Why are the icons on my tab navigator bar stacked on top of each other?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

```
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs'
import Home from '../Screens/Home'
import Appointment from '../Screens/Appointment'
import Profile from '../Screens/Profile'
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { FontAwesome } from '@expo/vector-icons';
//import Homenavigation from './Homenavigation'
//import Explores from '../Screens/Explores'

const Tab=createBottomTabNavigator()

export default function TabNavigation() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator screenOptions={{
        headerShown:false
        }}>
        <Tab.Screen name='Appointment' component={Appointment} 
        options={{
            tabBarIcon:({color,size})=>(
                <Ionicons name="calendar" size={size} color={color} />
            )
        }}/>
        <Tab.Screen name='Profile' component={Profile} 
        options={{
            tabBarIcon:({color,size})=>(
                <FontAwesome name="user-circle" size={size} color={color} />
            )
        }}/>
    </Tab.Navigator>
  )
}
```

The user desires a user interface (UI) configuration where distinct tabs are strategically spaced at equal intervals, accompanied by the respective tab names positioned below each corresponding icon within the bottom navigation bar of the application. Despite engaging in various attempts to achieve this desired layout, the user has encountered challenges and has not been successful in realizing the intended visual arrangement. The user is currently uncertain about the next steps to take in order to resolve this matter and is seeking guidance or potential solutions to enhance the layout of the application's bottom navigation bar.

Please see Code of parent: App.js:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Login from './App/Screens/Login';
import { ClerkProvider, SignedIn, SignedOut } from '@clerk/clerk-expo';
import SignInWithOAuth from './App/Components/SignInWithOAuth';
import Home from './App/Screens/Home';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import TabNavigation from './App/Navigations/TabNavigation';
import { useFonts } from 'expo-font';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <ClerkProvider publishableKey={"xxx"}>
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <StatusBar hidden />
      <SignedIn>
          <NavigationContainer>
            <TabNavigation/>
          </NavigationContainer>
      </SignedIn>
      <SignedOut>
      <Login/>
      </SignedOut>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </ClerkProvider>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Screenshot: [image]

Thanks a lot

Comment: Looks fine to me. Can you share a picture of the problem?

Comment: Also add the code for the parent of this component

Comment: These problems can sometimes be difficult to solve, and the same code could potentially render differently on various systems (or libraries used to build the code, etc).

Comment: I fixed it - was the align items and justify content at the end of app.js that were throwing things off. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sorted - the align items and justify content at the end of app.js were throwing things off. Removed these and now layout as desired - Thanks